# How to iterate through a List and convert it to a JSON object using JSON.NET (C# / ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have the following Object:

```
[Serializable]
public class Project
{
    private int projectId;
    private int userId;
    private String projectName;
    private String projectDescription;
    private DateTime startDate;
    private DateTime endDate;

...constructor + get/set methods removed
```

}

I have a a Class which has a variable:

```
private List<Project> projects
```

The corresponding get method is

```
public List<Project> getUserProjects()
    {
        return projects;
    }
```

I'm trying to convert this List to a JSON format to use with an AJAX service but the result is always [{},{}] (The user has 2 projects - if 3 than the result is [{},{},{}]

This is how I serialize the list of objects using JSON.NET:

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetProjects()
    {
         string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.getUserProjects());
         return json;
    }
```

Should I iterate through the list first or...?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:

I would like the JSON output to be like:

```
{
"Projects": [
{ "ProjectID":"theID" , "userID":"theuserID" , "ProjectName":"theName" , "ProjectDescription":"theDescription" , "startDate":"thedate" , "endDate":"theDate" }, 
{ "ProjectID":"theID" , "userID":"theuserID" , "ProjectName":"theName" , "ProjectDescription":"theDescription" , "startDate":"thedate" , "endDate":"theDate" }, 
...etc
]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your AJAX call so we can see how you're deserializing?

Comment: I'm currently only trying to see the string coming out of the service by a simple alert.

function pageLoad() {
            AjaxService.GetProjects(Test);
        }
function Test(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

Comment: According to JSON.net's web site your serialization code should work. I would guess the problem is with your deserialization in the AJAX call. How are you viewing the results of the call? Can you browse the URL you're attempting to retrieve the results from? If serialization is working correctly you should see the results in the browser.

Comment: Do you have public getters for the private properties listed in the question?

Comment: Yes, I have for most of them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this (System.Web.Script.Serialization). Try:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer();
String json = serializer.Serialize(listobject);
```

Comment: I receive the same output.

Comment: Just tested it and its because your fields are private, they can't be accessed outside the object. If you change them to public (or friend) it should work.